# Finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find eigenvalue and eigenfunction of $x^2y''-xy'+(\lambda+1)y=0$ with $y(1)=0=y(e)$.

I have found the equation to be Euler-cauchy equation
,so i try y=x^n,
which yields:
$n=1+\lambda i$
thus
 $y=x(Acos\lambda x+Bsin\lambda x)$
,with boundary condition $y(1)=0=y(e)$,
using cramer's rule,
i got:
$tan\lambda e=tan\lambda$
,$\lambda=m\pi/(e-1)$
can anyone tell me if my answer is true?

Comment: Hi new user! Welcome to Math.SE! Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the transformation $t = \log(x)$.

The differential equation will changed to 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dt} + (\lambda + 1)y = 0 $$

Solve it. Put inverse transformation. Apply initial conditions. Find out Eigen value and Eigen vectors.

Comment: hello,thank you for your help! But i can't understand your method.so i try another way to find the answer~ post it to my original question description~ can you help me check it?aiso welcome to elaborate your method^^

Comment: I hope the hint is sufficient to solve the problem.